# Which gas is a oxidizing agent as well as a reducing agent?

Tags: redox, hydrogen

I think it's Hydrogen, because,

$\ce{PbO + H2 -> Pb + H2O}$

Here $\ce{PbO}$ is reduced to $\ce{Pb}$ and $\ce{H2}$ acts as a reducing agent.

But, in $\ce{2K + H2 -> 2KH}$, hydrogen gains a electron and undergoes reduction 
Thus, $\ce{K}$ is oxidized to $\ce{KH}$ and hydrogen works as oxidizing agent.

My teacher says it's wrong but doesn't give any explanation.

Can someone explain why my reasoning is wrong.

Comment: Considering you made a typo here, and the first reaction is $\ce{PbO + H2 -> Pb + H2O},$ it looks OK to me. Probably you got a picky teacher and they also expected you to add conditions and states of aggregation, but this is something you need to sort out with them.

Comment: Like Einstein "said", "Everything is relative..."

Comment: @andselisk The question on the test asked for a one word answer. As far as I know everyone else wrote Sulphur Dioxide as the answer. I think I was absent the day she explained redox reactions, she probably mentioned it in class.

Comment: By the way, "Sulphur Dioxide" is a two-word answer! :-)

Comment: Some teachers are like a tram: they go on rails and won't swerve either way, no matter what. Indeed, SO2 is an oxidizing and a reducing agent. So is H2, and so is HI, and so are many other gases (arguably, more than those that aren't).

Comment: @MaxW could you please elaborate :-)

Comment: @Padmanava - Look at the position of the half cell reaction in a table of reduction potentials. The *relative* position of the half-cell reaction tells you for which reactions the half-cell can be an oxidant, and for which reactions can be an reductant.

Comment: Another case is N2, forming NH3 and NO with H2 resp. O2. But both need special conditions. Another case is NO2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm guessing your teacher is looking for [sulfur dioxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur_dioxide) as the answer, but I don't see how or why you're supposed to be able to arrive to this answer logically. Either you'd need to read about it specifically, or maybe you're supposed to stare at [a table of standard reduction potentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_(data_page)) and notice that $\ce{SO2}$ appears as both a reagent and as a product with comparable voltages:

$$
\begin{array}{}
\ce{SO2(aq) + 4 H+(aq) + 4 e- &<=>& S(s) + 2 H2O(l)} &  E^\circ = \pu{+0.50 V}\\
\ce{SO2(aq) + 2 H2O(l) &<=>& SO4^2-(aq) + 4 H+(aq) + 2 e-} &  E^\circ = \pu{-0.17 V}
\end{array}
$$

(The bottom equation is the inverse of what you would find in a reduction potential table)

Extrapolating from these aqueous potentials, it appears $\ce{SO2}$ is a modest reductant and a weak oxidiser, but both reactions can be accessed in reasonable conditions.

I think you're technically correct (as Ivan mentions), but what makes hydrogen gas a "less correct" answer is that it only rarely acts an oxidiser (in the presence of very strong reducing agents, such as alkali metals), whereas it can act as a reductant much more commonly. Compare these equations with the ones above:

$$
\begin{array}{}
\ce{H2(g) + 2 e- &<=>& 2 H^-(aq, extrapolated)} &  E^\circ = \pu{-2.3 V}\\
\ce{H2(g) &<=>& 2 H+(aq) + 2 e-} &  E^\circ = \pu{+0.00 V}
\end{array}
$$

([Reference for the hydride potential](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/351/6279/1314))

Note the much larger gap in potential between the two reactions. In this sense, the reducing nature of $\ce{H2}$ vastly overwhelms its oxidising nature, so most people will think of it as a reducing gas.

Comment: My first thought was also hydrogen, and I was once a chemistry teacher myself. If the question was "Name a gas that can both reduce and oxidize reactants," then H2 is a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

The first candidate that comes to my mind is **carbon monoxide.** Electropositive metals such as magnesium[[1]](https://doi.org/10.1080/00102209208951843) can use it as a combustion oxidizer, while iron is commonly smelted using carbon monoxide as a reducing agent.

**References**

1. E. Ya. SHAFIROVICH & U.I. GOLDSHLEGER (1992) "Combustion of Magnesium Particles in CO2/CO Mixtures". *Combustion Science and Technology* **84**:1-6, 33-43. https://doi.org/10.1080/00102209208951843